# How to count number of items in row in SQL and display as a group

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently trying to bring two tables together. An employee table and a department table. Both share an ID and I Have managed to join them together successfully using the following code.

```
SELECT department.dept_id, employee.dept_id, employee.salary
From department 
INNER Join employee ON department.dept_id=employee.dept_id
ORDER BY employee.dept_id ASC
```

This produces a table like...

```
| 10 | 10 | 12000 |
| 20 | 20 |  5000 |
| 20 | 20 |  7500 |
| 20 | 20 | 15000 |
| 20 | 20 | 35000 |
| 30 | 30 | 15000 |
| 30 | 30 | 25000 |
| 40 | 40 | 25000 |
| 40 | 40 |  5000 |
```

How would i go about producing it so that it could look like...

```
   10      | 1     | 12000
   20      | 4     | 62500
   30      | 2     | 40000
   40      | 2     | 30000
```

where the second column is a count of the amount of times they appear?

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`, use `COUNT()` and `SUM()` aggregate functions!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    department.dept_id
    ,COUNT(department.dept_id)
    ,SUM(employee.salary)
From department 
INNER Join employee ON department.dept_id=employee.dept_id
GROUP BY department.dept_id
ORDER BY department.dept_id ASC
```

Comment: Hi, when i run this i get this error message....

column "employee.dept_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 15: ORDER BY employee.dept_id ASC

Comment: Missed your `ORDER BY` clause. Give it a go now